# Retrieving a single Realm object based on the value of a property

Tags: realm, swift3

How to return a class with values while retrieving data with Realm?
I am trying to use this code, but swift 3 not allowed:

```
static func getInfoById(id: String) -> DataInfo {
    let scope = DataInfo ()
    let realm = try! Realm()
    scope = realm.objects(DataInfo.self).filter("IdInfo == %@", id)
    return scope
}
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Your code `realm.objects(DataInfo.self).filter("IdInfo == %@", id)` returns  a `Results<DataInfo>` (a filtered collection of DataInfo), thus you're not really returning a `DataInfo` object. You can call `scope.first!` to get one `DataInfo` from the results.

```
static func getInfoById(id: String) -> DataInfo {
    let realm = try! Realm()
    let scope = realm.objects(DataInfo.self).filter("IdInfo == %@", id)
    return scope.first!
}
```

Although, I don't recommend force-unwrapping since there can be no items found, and force-unwrapping a nil value results in a crash. Thus you can return a `DataInfo?` instead.

```
static func getInfoById(id: String) -> DataInfo? {
    let realm = try! Realm()
    let scope = realm.objects(DataInfo.self).filter("IdInfo == %@", id)
    return scope.first
}
```

Alternatively, if you have explicitly stated in your Realm Object subclass that `IdInfo` is your primary key, you can use `realm.object(ofType: DataInfo.type, forPrimaryKey: id)` instead.

```
static func getInfoById(id: String) -> DataInfo? {
    let realm = try! Realm()
    return realm.object(ofType: DataInfo.self, forPrimaryKey: id)
}
```

Comment: last code shows Cannot convert result type 'Object?" to expected type DataInfo, can I use as! DataInfo to parse?

Comment: My bad, the return type of the function should be an optional, i.e. `DataInfo?`.

Comment: ok, now appear: `Type DataInfo has no member type` ... I guess is `DataInfo.self`

Comment: Apologies, another typo. `DataInfo.type` should be `DataInfo.self`. Edited the answer.

Comment: I love you :Hearts: